# Set up usb microphone for google assistant

Tags: raspberry-pi3, microphone, google-assistant-sdk

I'm trying to set up the Google home assistant on my pi3, but I'm having issues with the microphone. When I ran a test on the microphone it says no file exists:

```
$ arecord --format=S16_LE --duration=5 --rate=16k --file-type=raw out.raw            
arecord: main:722: audio open error: No such file or directory
```

According to instructions from google developers I need to set up a directory called .asoundrc with the following commands:

```
pcm.!default {
  type asym
  capture.pcm "mic"
  playback.pcm "speaker"
}
pcm.mic {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:<card number>,<device number>"
  }
}
pcm.speaker {
  type plug
  slave {
    pcm "hw:<card number>,<device number>"
  }
}
```

When I run this command though I get this error:

```
bash: !default: event not found
```

I would appreciate any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run it as a command manually. You just need to create a file called ".asoundrc" in your home directory. Use [this link](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/develop/python/hardware/audio) for more information and how to troubleshoot the audio problems.

Comment: And make sure you have add the card number and device number instead of `'<card number>,<device number>'`
Read the instructions in the above link properly. :)